# Angular setup with nginx cannot hit the api

Tags: angular, nginx

I'm new on Angular development. So I have serious problem is I cannot deploy angular on server

If I try on local, the code is running well and can hit the api using proxy

for the Api build with spring and deploy on `heroku`

and for the Angular I using Aws Lightsail with nginx configuration

1. I'm run `ng build` for get the dist folder
2. and then I move all file inside `dist/my-folder-generate/` to `/var/ww/html`
3. when I open via browser, the Angular running well but I cannot hit the api

this is my nginx configurations

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    
    server_name _;
    
    location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
       error_page 405 =200 $uri;
    }
}
```

this is my `angular.json`

```
"serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "my-app:build:production",
              "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "my-app:build:development",
              "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "my-app:build",
            "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
          }
 },
```

for the `proxy.conf.json`

```
{
  "/api": {
      "target": "https://my-api.herokuapp.com",
      "secure": false,
      "logLevel": "debug",
      "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

and this how I consume the api

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
const AUTH_API = '/api/';
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    accept: ' application/json',
    'Content-Type': ' application/json',
  }),
};
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  login(username: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(
      AUTH_API + 'auth/login',
      {
        username,
        password,
      },
      httpOptions
    );
  }
}
```

for sure this config running well on local but not on server, can anyone help me? may I have a mistake about server configurations?

Comment: What do you mean by you cannot hit the API ? Are you getting errors ?

Comment: for sure this is login page, so I just fill username and password and then submit. on my local after I click submit button, this will be redirect to dashboard, but on the server when I click submit button, page not redirect and stay on login page without an error

Comment: you can add a location in nginx with /api name and proxy_pass this location to your api path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @mojtaba suggestions for add `/api`. So I add nginx configuration like this

```
location /api {
  proxy_method POST;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_pass https://my-api.herokuapp.com;

}
```

so for who have trouble and same case like me you can use this block

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    
    server_name _;
    
    location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
       error_page 405 =200 $uri;
    }
}

location /api {
  proxy_method POST;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_pass https://my-api.herokuapp.com;    
}
```